# Given the linear system $Ax=b$; where $A$ has $m$ rows and $n$ columns, proof the following statements

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

1.-if $rk(A)=m \leq n$ (A has full row rank), then the system has at least 1 solution

2.-if $rk(A)=n \leq m$ (A has full column rank), then the system has at most 1 solution

3.-if $rk(A)=n=m$ (A has full rank), then the system has 1 unique solution

Observation: $rk(A)$ = the amount of pivots of its Row Echelon Form

Edit:

for 1 I know that a)dim of $C(A) \leq m,$ therefore if $dim(C(A))+dim(N(A))=n$, and then replacing a) in the last equality, we have $dim(N(A)) \geq n-m$, where $n-m \geq 1$ because the statement says so, so if dim of $N(A)$ is one or bigger our system has one or more solutions. But I'm not quite sure about this last statement and if it's true I don't exactly know why, so if anyone could help I would be very grateful, thanks

Comment: Hi @westenger. When you post a question, please make sure to  also show what you have tried and indicate where you got stuck. Otherwise, your question may be downvoted (as it has already happened).

Comment: sure, sorry, it's my first time in this website and I didn't think about that.
I'll explain what I did